# Different results with cut and dd on binary files

Tags: linux, binaryfiles, elf, cut, dd

My Environment:

```
CentOS 6.5
```

I need to extract some part of the ELF file.

When I use `dd` command as follows, I have no problem:

```
$dd if=a.out of=a.cut1 bs=1 skip=16
```

On the other hand, when I use `cut` command as follows, the created file has much less size than I expected:

```
$cut --bytes=16- a.out > a.cut2
```

---

For example, I created a.out by compiling the following sample c program with gcc (v. 4.4.7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Then, I execute `dd` and `cut` commands as above, I have files with following sizes:

```
a.out - 6415 bytes
a.cut1 - 6399 bytes
a.cut2 - 6356 bytes
```

I wonder why the `cut` command reduces the size more than I specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cut` will skip the first 16 bytes *from each line* whereas `dd` doesn't care about lines and skips just the first 16 bytes from the whole file.

If the file contains newlines - which is perfectly valid for binary files - then `cut` will yield a different result than `dd`.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Now I can understand the reason clearly.